# How can I access an existing AWS database via .PEM file in R?

Tags: r, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

To make a long story short, a former developer have setup a database(MongoDB) at Amazon Web Services(AWS), through EC2. Now to the problem, all I have got thus far is the information in the previous sentence as well as a .PEM file, and I would like to access the database through R, is that possible?

Sorry that I don’t have more information at the moment, but I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: You need to be extremely cautious if your database is on the Internet and not properly secured, because [this is still happening](https://continuum.cisco.com/2017/01/09/hacker-gold-rush-ransoms-mongodb-databases-en-masse/).  A .pem file is not a specific type of file, it is an encoding used for multiple (incompatible) types of files.  Please open your .pem file with a text editor.  It will say `-----BEGIN SOME_KIND_OF_THING-----` which identifies the type of file it is (e.g. it may say `RSA PRIVATE KEY` or `CERTIFICATE` or something else).  How to proceed depends on what you see in that file.

Comment: Thanks alot @Michael-sqlbot for your reply and for your information/Tip. It is a RSA PRIVATE KEY.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PEM file you can follow the directions to access the instance [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) Now this assumes the instance has a public ip address that is internet reachable with port 22 open.
 [If it does not you'll need a vpn setup to reach the private instances.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html)

If you do not have the PEM file you'll need to re-create instance by snapshotting it and creating a new instances based off of that snapshot, with a PEM key you do have access to. [Here is the AWS documentation on that process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair)

Comment: Thank you @strongjz for your answer, I see that I lack some information at the current moment.